# How do I browse files in my `.backupbundle` backup?

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I am currently trying to access my Time Machine backups manually, because the Time Machine feature was a little to slow for me and I needed the finder search. Before Catalina this was possible with the `.sparsebundle` but since then not longer. Every time I double-click the `.backupbundle` it says "This resource is currently not available".

I wonder if there is a way to mount/open this file to browse my backups. I read that renaming it to `.sparsebundle` would work but I don't want to destroy my backups – we all know that macOS sometimes do things different from expected ^^.

My Backup is saved on an Airport Extreme by the way. Which still works pretty well!

Comment: You already know the correct answer (rename the bundle).  You should make a backup somewhere else beforehand if you are (rightly) worried about making a mess!

Comment: What a shame.. I hope they will implement something like that in the future.

Comment: Sadly it is typical of the rushed/incomplete nature of Catalina.  I just hope that 10.16 concentrates on fixing up the missing bits of Catlina.

Comment: This! Catalina doesn't feel like an Apple product. Tim Cook wouldn't be proud of it. I mean look at Mail which opens randomly when u connect a Gmail account... Devs got lazy.

Answer (score -1):

Try right-clicking (or Ctrl-clicking) on the bundle in the Finder and choosing "Show Package Contents".

Comment: That will show the bundle contents, of which the bulk are the 'band' files,

Comment: Sorry but this does not help.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, sorry about that. I tried a few experiments with it and it *looked* like it was doing the right thing, but they were "synthetic" as I don't have a 'real' Time Machine example of that kind of bundle to play with.